# Allure reporting tools setup with Java + selenium + cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm, allure

I know it is a very basic question but certain things is not clear to me. I used extent report with java selenium for the automation testing but I would like to try allure reporting. My understanding is that not only allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor jars is sufficient. I need to have tomcat/jetty server installed? Can any one please explain to me how to setup Allure2 + selenium+ cucumber in eclipse for automation?
Thanks

Comment: Official documentation is a good starting point https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/